# Embed mp3 in infowindows of kmz file?

Tags: google-earth, kmz, google-earth-pro

Is there a way to embed audio files (mp3) into the infowindows of markers in a kmz so that the audio is available offline? I'd like the files to be in the kmz so the kmz can be downloaded as a whole package before entering the field and no streaming in the field would be required. We don't want to use the virtual "Tour" function, rather we want people to access audio clips via the infowindows when they get to certain points in the field.